How to simulate or manually start the NextJS-TopLoader Component
I use NextJs-TopLoader for top loading bar animation when changing route using the <Link /> component (it works) but when I use router.push('/somewhere') function, it doesn't work. 
I've looked through the props in the NextTopLoader object. 
I found a NextTopLoader.call() and  NextTopLoader.caller but it's documentation says its not it
and I couldn't find anything else.
Below is an example of a code test run code that you could use from:
export default function LoginPage() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [user, setUser] = useState<userLoginData>({
        email: '',
        password: ''
    });
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    const handleSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {

        event.preventDefault();
        setIsLoading(true);

        try {
            // API call
            const response = await axios.post('/api/login', user);

            if (response.status !== 200) {
                toast.error('Login unsuccessful. Please try again!');
                setIsLoading(false);
                return;
            }
            console.log('Login successful:', response.data);
            // Handle successful login here
            toast.success('Login successful!');
            // NextTopLoader.caller();
            router.push('/dashboard');
        } catch (error) {
            toast.error('Login failed!');
            console.log('Login failed!:', (error as Error).message);
            setIsLoading(false);
        }
    };


To make the NextJs-TopLoader animate when you use router.push, you’ll need to start and complete the loading bar manually. The component does not automatically track navigation events initiated by router.push, so you need to trigger it yourself in handleSubmit.
Here’s how you can update your code to accomplish this:
First, ensure you import NextTopLoader.
Then, create a reference to control NextTopLoader and manually start and stop it around the router.push.
Here's an example:
import NextTopLoader from 'nextjs-toploader';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import toast from 'react-toastify';

export default function LoginPage() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const loaderRef = useRef(null); 
    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        email: '',
        password: ''
    });
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setIsLoading(true);
        
        
        loaderRef.current?.continuousStart();

        try {
            // API call
            const response = await axios.post('/api/login', user);

            if (response.status !== 200) {
                toast.error('Login unsuccessful. Please try again!');
                setIsLoading(false);
                loaderRef.current?.complete(); // Stop loader if failed
                return;
            }
            console.log('Login successful:', response.data);
            toast.success('Login successful!');

            
            router.push('/dashboard').then(() => {
                loaderRef.current?.complete();
            });
        } catch (error) {
            toast.error('Login failed!');
            console.log('Login failed!:', error.message);
            setIsLoading(false);
            loaderRef.current?.complete(); // Stop loader on error
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <NextTopLoader ref={loaderRef} />
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                {/* form inputs for email and password */}
                <button type="submit" disabled={isLoading}>Login</button>
            </form>
        </>
    );
}

